# jxcore can't protect source code

Tags: javascript, jxcore

I saw from [blog](https://modernweb.com/code-protection-and-packaging-for-node-js-projects-with-jxcore/) that [jxcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) can create an executable based on a js code (to run as a command line application) and protect the source code from being seen easily.

But when I tried the following, I saw the excutable file (in Ubuntu) still contains the source

```
# jx package test1.js
# change library and extract attribute in file test1.jxp to be false
# jx compile test1.jxp
# grep "this is test1" test1 
  Binary file test1 matches
```

The little JS file test1.js

```
console.log("this is test1");
```

I understand there is no perfect way of protecting an application from being reversed. But I just hoped there is no simple way (like "strings" command) to grab source code out of executable.

Comment: See if you can grep for `console.log`. If not then the string is encoded the same way it would be in a binary file, and the actual code is still being hidden.

Comment: And if that's the case and hiding the strings is really critical for you, you could try encoding them, i.e.: `var test1 = atob('this is test1')`

Comment: @jdgregson Your `atob()` example doesn't work. For one, the source string is still likely to appear in the binary. Moreover, `atob()` only works on Base64 data. For instance, `btoa(atob('hello world')) == 'helloworlQ=='`.

Comment: @duskwuff That was more or less an example, and any other encoding method could be used. But the source strings don't always have to be in the  file if their encoded version is ASCII representable. For example, you could use binary and say `var test1 = '01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100';` and then just call `console.log(decode(test1));` (where `decode` is your own purpose-build decoder).

Comment: Nice try @jdgregson :-) Like @duskwuff pointed out, whatever your js source can be easily extracted (by something like `strings`) :-)  But your suggestion of using a purpose built decoder is indeed interesting. Care to give an example?

Comment: @packetie I put together this example with the strings converted to their ASCII value. It seems to work pretty well: https://jsfiddle.net/xzmscae5/1/

Comment: Thanks @jdgregson for working out an example. I meant I am inspired by your mentioning of "purpose built decoder" and going to implement it in C++ and compile it as an addon for node.js. Even though it's not perfect, I believe it would be good enough in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you read is, simply put, outdated and wrong. [The "protection" features provided by JXCore were severely flawed](https://markhaa.se/cracking-jxcore-again.html), and were largely removed in later releases of the project.

Do not use JXCore. [Development on the project was halted in March 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160401190926/http://www.nubisa.com:80/nubisa-halting-active-development-on-jxcore-platform/); it has fallen significantly behind the node.js platform, and provides no real benefits over open solutions like [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

Comment: This makes sense. I downloaded JXCore and was trying to follow along to reproduce the problem, but anything I "compiled" simply spewed gibberish and crashed bash. I certainly wouldn't trust one of these programs to run on a client's machine even if I ever got one to compile on my dev machine.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff for the comment. I did try `pkg` but it too doesn't offer some protection.  Wonder if there is a way to compile a js file into some sort of byte code and include it an executable.